# Finding the difference btw two time inputs in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, time

I am developing a webpage to collect information about a person's sleep. Specifically, I am required to find the difference in time between two user inputs which may or may not cross midnight.

I am pretty new to programming in general so am trying to go on using just the skills I am familiar with, though would also like to know if there is an easier way!

The code I have written is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function timeSec() {

  var btHours = document.getElementById('bedtimeHours').value;

  if (btHours == "") {
    btHours = 0;
  } 

  var btMins = document.getElementById('bedtimeMins').value;

  if (btMins == "") {
    btMins = 0;
  }

  var btSleepTillMidnight = 0;
  var btSecTotal = (btHours*3600) + (btMins*60);

  document.getElementById('btSec').value = btSecTotal;

  if (btHours > 12) {
    btSleepTillMidnight = 24*3600 - btSecTotal;
  }
  if (btHours <= 12) {
    btSleepTillMidnight = ( -Math.abs(btSecTotal));
  }

  var wtHours = document.getElementById('waketimeHours').value;

  if (wtHours == "") {
    wtHours = 0;
  }

  var wtMins = document.getElementById('waketimeMins').value;

  if (wtMins == "") {
    wtMins = 0;
  }

  var wtSecTotal = (wtHours*3600) + (wtMins*60);

  document.getElementById('wtSec').value = wtSecTotal;

  var diffSec = wtSecTotal + btSleepTilMidnight;

  document.getElementById('diffSec').value = diffSec;

  var diffHours = diffSec/3600;

  document.getElementById('diffHours').value = diffHours;
}

</script>
```

My HTML is as follows, and is pretty much designed to pinpoint errors during development:

```
<form method="post" action="" name="PSQI" id="PSQI">

  Bedtime: 
  <input type="number" name="bedtimeHours" id="bedtimeHours" min="0" step="1" max="24" value=""> Hours
  <input type="number" name="bedtimeMins" id="bedtimeMins" min="0" step="10" max="50" value=""> Minutes

  <br>
  Waketime:
  <input type="number" name="waketimeHours" id="waketimeHours" min="0" step="1" max="24" value=""> Hours
  <input type="number" name="waketimeMins" id="waketimeMins" min="0" step="10" max="50" value=""> Minutes

  <input type="button" value="Score" onclick="timeSec();">
  <br>
  btSec: <input type="text" name="btSec" id="btSec" value="">
  <br>
  wtSec: <input type="text" name="wtSec" id="wtSec" value="">
  <br>
  diffSec: <input type="text" name="diffSec" id="diffSec" value="">
  <br>
  diffHours: <input type="text" name="diffHours" id="diffHours" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: ...and your question is?

Comment: For debugging use the dev tool bars. All major browsers have those. You can bring it up by hitting F12. You can write to the console using `console.log(something)` this makes debugging a lot easier. Also you can put `debugger` in your code. Whenever the dev tool is active it will halt script execution and allow you to debug your code step by step.

Comment: @mouser brilliant thanks.. I apologize about the lack of clear question.. it wasn't working in my browser for some reason, with no values being reported in diffSec and diffHours. the debugging tip is great though.. didn't know about that. cheers!

Comment: @RoryLattimer Glad to help a follow coder discover great new tools :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there's a question here or not, so maybe you're in the wrong place.

I don't know why you're using seconds if the resolution is minutes. Your code seems a bit convoluted, consider the following.

If you pass a reference from the button using *this*, you can get a reference to the form and save using *getElementById*, e.g.:

```
<input type="button" value="Score" onclick="timeSec(this);">
```

Now in the function you can get the form and access the form controls by name, e.g.

```
function timeSec(el) {
  var form = el.form;
  var btSecTotal = form.bedtimeHours.value * 3600 + form.bedtimeMins.value * 60;
  var wtSecTotal = form.waketimeHours.value * 3600 + form.waketimeMins.value * 60;

  form.btSec.value = btSecTotal;
  form.wtSec.value = wtSecTotal;
  var secTotal = wtSecTotal - btSecTotal;

  if (secTotal < 0) secTotal += 24*60*60;

  form.diffSec.value = secTotal;
  form.diffHours.value = secondsToHM(secTotal);
}

// Convert seconds to hh:mm format
function secondsToHM(secs) {
  function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
  return z(secs/3600 | 0) + ':' + z((secs%3600)/60 | 0);
}
```

If someone can't sleep more than 24 hours, get the difference between the bed time and wake time by subtracting wake time from bed time and if it's negative, subtract the difference from 24.

Conversely, if the wake time is earlier than the bed time, add 24hrs to the wake time. To allow for sleep time greater than 24 hours, a slightly different algorithm is required but you will also need something else to tell you that they've slept that long (a "next day" checkbox or similar).

Lastly, don't depend on the browser controlling the values based on the input element attributes. User input should be validated and out–of–range or invalid values should be detected and users asked to fix them. The above doesn't do any of that (it's not hard to do).

Comment: thanks very much for the suggestions.. sorry wasn't clear on the question.. the diffSec and diffHour inputs were not populating when i called the function.. Ill modify my code and see where I stand.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neater way to check the `""` zero length input. Also, you don't need to repeat `var` every time.

```
var btHours = document.getElementById('bedtimeHours').value || 0,
    btMins = document.getElementById('bedtimeMins').value || 0,
    btSecTotal = (btHours*3600) + (btMins*60);
```

an inline if-else

```
var btSleepTillMidnight = (btHours > 12) ? 24*3600 - btSecTotal : ( -Math.abs(btSecTotal));
```

Comment: There's no need to check for an empty string, since in multiplication an empty string will convert to 0 anyway. Other non–number strings will produce NaN, but that isn't guarded against anyway.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, I could have spent more time thinking. You did good job.